# Unable to create foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

## Error code: 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint

I have tried all options like changing the default storage engine using

```
SET default_storage_engine=ENGINE
```

But I'm unable to create this foreign key constraints. I'm using Mysql 5.5.
Anybody can help me out.

```
create table if not exists pallets(
    palletId serial,
    goodsType varchar(25),
    desitination varchar(25),
    primary key (palletId)
);
create table if not exists storage(
    id serial,
    palletId integer,
    primary key (id),
    constraint FK _Pallet foreign key (palletId) REFERENCES pallets(palletId)
);
```

Comment: The 2 columns have to have the same datatype. `Integer` is not the same as `serial`. So try `bigint unsigned` instead of `integer` (or use `integer` in `pallets`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datatype of the foreign key column(s) must *match* the datatype of the referenced (usually primary key) column(s) in the referenced table.

Error 1215 is the expected behavior when we attempt to create a foreign key constraint that would violate this restriction.

According to the MySQL Reference Manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html

**`SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`.**

---

So the table definition for `pallets` is equivalent to:

```
create table pallets
( palletId   BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
  --         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
, ...
, primary key (palletId)
);
```

A foreign key reference will need to be of the same datatype `BIGINT UNSIGNED`

e.g.

```
create table storage
( id ...
, palletId   BIGINT UNSIGNED 
  --         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
, primary key (id)
, constraint FK_storage_pallets foreign key (palletId) REFERENCES pallets(palletId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SERIAL datatype as primary key, the foreign key should be BIGINT UNSIGNED

```
create table if not exists pallets(
    palletId serial,
    goodsType varchar(25),
    desitination varchar(25),
    primary key (palletId)
);
create table if not exists storage(
    id serial,
    palletId bigint unsigned,
    primary key (id),
    constraint FK _Pallet foreign key (palletId) REFERENCES pallets(palletId)
);
```